# PIL working in Terminal, but not via IDLE

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use Pillow. I've followed the installation instructions on this site:
 http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/gui/how-to-use-pillow

When I type the following into my terminal window:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image
>>>
```

It doesn't give me any errors, so assuming the linked site is correct, this means that Pillow is correctly installed.
However, when I try to use the PIL library from the Python IDLE, like this:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Python gives an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Sample_application.py",
line 3, in <module>
from PIL import Image
ImportError: No module named 'PIL'
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using mac OSX 10.9, Mavericks

Comment: You are probably using the IDLE installed with a *different* Python version or installation. What does `import sys; print(sys.prefix)` produce in either environment?

Comment: Ow, that's probably the problem! In Terminal I get 2.7, via IDLE I get 3.4. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: You could run `/usr/bin/idle` to run the system-installed IDLE, perhaps. Or use `python3.4 -m pip install Pillow` to install Pillow into Python 3.4 as well.

Comment: Thanks man! Installing Pillow into Python 3.4 was the fix I was looking for.

Comment: great! Worked out your options as an actual answer for you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least *two* Python installations on your system; the default system-provided 2.7 and Python 3.4.

Your `pip` command is tied to Python 2.7; you could run the version of IDLE with that version with:

```
/usr/bin/idle
```

Or you can install Pillow into Python 3.4 with:

```
python3.4 -m pip install Pillow
```